# Postfix relay from local network

Tags: postfix

I have problem with postfix relay sendind mail from local network. 
I receive next error

```
    Jul  9 23:00:46 ext1 postfix/smtpd[2301]: warning: inet_protocols: disabling IPv6    name/address support: Protocol not supported
    Jul  9 23:00:46 ext1 postfix/smtpd[2301]: warning: TLS has been selected, but TLS support is not compiled in
    Jul  9 23:00:46 ext1 postfix/smtpd[2301]: connect from unknown[192.168.0.173]
    Jul  9 23:00:46 ext1 postfix/smtpd[2301]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[192.168.0.173]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[192.168.0.173]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<user@exxx> to=<xxx@yyy> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.0.173]>
    Jul  9 23:00:46 ext1 postfix/smtpd[2301]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.0.173]
    Jul  9 23:00:46 ext1 dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<user@xxx>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.0.173, lip=192.168.0.47
    Jul  9 23:00:46 ext1 dovecot: POP3(user@xxx): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0,     del=0/0, size=0
```

My main.cf

```
    queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/local/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/local/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/db/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = localhost
mydomain = localdomain
myorigin = $myhostname
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks_style = host
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8
alias_maps = hash:/etc/mail/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/mail/aliases
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
    ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/local/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/local/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/local/bin/mailq
setgid_group = maildrop
html_directory = /usr/local/share/doc/postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/local/man
sample_directory = /usr/local/etc/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/local/share/doc/postfix
virtual_mailbox_base = /usr/mail/
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid             = 65534
virtual_uid_maps                = static:65534
virtual_gid_maps                = static:65534
virtual_transport               = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = $mynetworks
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
```

Can you please help to find where problem is.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should change "localhost" and "localdomain" to your actual hostname and domain.
Second, you've got two different parameters for trusted hosts - you've got

```
mynetworks_style = host
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8
```

The first one says to trust only this host. There's no reason to have it when you're specifying networks on the next line and it may be what's causing your problems.

Answer (score 1):

I usually define allowed networks in mynetworks file inside /etc/postfix dir.

Then add

```
mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
```

inside main.cf.

Save and restart postfix

Answer (score 0):

I got this relay problem when i tried to send an email with terminal:

```
nc mail.mydomainname.nl 25
220 mail.mydomainname.nl ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
EHLO mydomainname.nl
250-mail.mydomainname.nl
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
MAIL FROM: info@mydomainname.nl
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: info@yourdomainname.nl
554 5.7.1 <info@mydomainname.nl>: Relay access denied
```

The postfix relay error 554 5.7.1 (and also the postfix error 451 4.3.0: Temporary lookup failure) was/were solved by adapting /etc/postfix/main.cf and adding the external ip-address of my mailserver to the mynetworks line:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

where `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is the ip-address you get when you use the whatismyip test.